# how to use lastInsertId() if the column called different

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a function which insert my data into my database. But at the same time i want that my javascript add the content to my list #div.

my php file

```
function xhrInsertPost() {
    // echo $_POST[''];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $msg   = $_POST['msg'];

    $sth = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO posts (post_title, post_content) VALUES (:title, :msg) ');
    $sth->execute(array(
        ':title' => $title,
        ':msg'   => $msg
        ));
    $data = array( 'post_title' => $title, 'id' => $this->db->lastInsertId());
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

my js file

```
$('#postText').submit(function() {
var url = $(this).attr('action');    
var data = $(this).serialize();

$.post(url, data, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.msg);
  $('#listMsg').append('<tr><td>' + data.post_title + '</td><td><a class="del" rel="'+ data.post_id + '" href="#"> delete</a></td></tr>');
}, 'json');

return false;
```

});

i think it didn't work because my column called different. my code works but my "data.post_id" is undefined.. in my other method (if i refresh the page) it works

Comment: no post_id in the array , this is just 'id' in php array so you can use data.id instead of data.post_id

Comment: thanks yousef, i change the name of my variable but unfortunately, it also not work.. my column in my database called "post_id" and i know the function lastInsertId() will not mentioned that.. i changed the name from my column now form "post_id" to "id" .. this works! but how can i call a different name?

Comment: look as I understood .. you make a post form like twitter and you need to insert the form data into database and then show the post inserted in your news feed div by javascript .. right?  what is the different name? different name of what?

Comment: My database table called "posts" and the id is insert into the column named "post_id" .. if the column named only "id" it works! Would it be able to get the lastInsertId('post_id') .. or is it only able with the named of Id

Comment: And a notice to your last question.. if i insert a new post, i want to extend my list immediatly (live).. if i refresh the page, there is another call which get all items of my List. So that is the reason why i want to use lastInsertId()

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp may help

Comment: and this is for how to return json .. No need at all to change the column name  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281647/jquery-getting-array-from-php-json-encode